# How to nest Sequelize associations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to nest associations using Node/Sequelize/PostgreSQL.  It is a fairly common scenario (I believe), but I have yet to determine how to do it.  Here is my scenario.

Person
  -- Location  (1:m)
    ----- SubLocation (1:m)

The Person model has a belongsToMany association which is working great.  I now have a PersonLocation table which holds the ids of both Person and Location and the Location(s) are returned with the Person query.

Here's where it gets tricky.  I now need to associate the PersonLocation with a Sublocation which also needs to be a 1:m relationship.

Person.belongsToMany(Location, {through: 'PersonLocation'});

**--This is how I envision it to work, but since I just defined the PersonLocation association, I cannot access it this way.**

PersonLocation.belongsToMany(SubLocation, {through: 'PersonLocationSubLocation'});

The Person would then have 1:m Locations, then each of those Locations could have multiple 1:m SubLocations.  When doing the query on the Person, I would want to see all Person/Locations/SubLocations for that person.

The database would look something like this

**Person**
Id
Name

**Location**
Id
Name

**SubLocation**
Id
Name

**PersonLocation**
Id
PersonId
LocationId

**PersonLocationSubLocation**
Id
PersonLocationId
SubLocationId

Any ideas how to achieve this using Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

sequelize-embed

Easily insert and update sequelize models with deeply nested associations